# C++ static pointer to pointer to value

Tags: c++, pointers, reverse-engineering, memory-address

I am really new to C++ and don't quite understand how to use pointers right. I have a dll that I want to inject into a program. I know that at the address "program.exe + 0x29D2CC" points to is another pointer to a struct I called entList in this struct there are multiple instances of my class ent. So I am trying to get the first object of the entList (I know for sure that the first object is valid).

In previous projects I was able to do it like this:

```
entList* entityList = *(entList**)address;
```

But here it doesn't work. Then I tried to use this function I also used in other projects.

```
uintptr_t mem::FindDMAAddy(uintptr_t ptr, std::vector<unsigned int> offsets) {
    uintptr_t addr = ptr;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < offsets.size(); ++i) {
        addr = *(uintptr_t*)addr;
        addr += offsets[i];
    }
    return addr;
}

entList* entityList = (entList*)mem::FindDMAAddy(moduleBase, { 0x29D2CC, 0x0 });
```

Using this my injector gives me the error "the remote code wasn't able to load the module".

I searched about this in the internet but since I am new to this I didn't know what to search for exactly and didn't find anything that helped me. Can anyone tell me how I can get the entList* or what method I could use to get objects that are at the end of a pointer chain?

Comment: If you are _really new_ to C++ I recommend starting at the beginning. Cutting in line is frowned upon.

Comment: I don't think that it is a problem because I have done two not too small projects in C++ and it's not my first programming language I learned so I understand the logic and syntax of code. I just struggle with more complex use of pointers to get values in memory.

Comment: I don't understand how the error you are getting is related to the code you are posting. Can you read any address in the process?

Comment: Yes I generally can read addresses in the process. I think the error with the function FindDMAAddy is that I am using a 0 offset. At least this error occurred every time I used a 0 offset.